# How to print Promoted to front page to new block?

Tags: 7, views, blocks

I have article,news,video types for content. Now I checked `Promoted to front page` for print article/news/video, etc content to any block. Now, how to print `10` result `Promoted to front page` article/news/video to new block of index using views Module?

Comment: So you basically want one of us to create a view for you that prints 10 results of each content type?

Comment: @saadlulu: no! i need to show all content from all type with `Promoted to front page` with limit 10.

Comment: and you want the results to be mixed? like if you have 10 content of each, you want 3 articles 3 basic pages and 4 events for instance?

Comment: @saadlulu: i want to sort with date(last added) and limit 10. so this auto mixed.

Comment: @saadlulu: Of course, Your Idea is good. but, how to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to show 10 posts promoted to the front page in a block.

The Views module comes with a "Front page" view. By default, it is disabled, and you need to enable it. Once you did it, you can edit it: Click on *edit*.

[image: screenshot]

On the next page, click on the "Add" button you see on the top left, and select *Block*.

[image: screenshot]

On the next page, select "Access: None" under *Block settings*. (The link is just the *None* word.) Change the access to *Permission* (first page), and *View published content* (second page). (To pass to the second page, click on *Apply*.)

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Save the view. (The button is on the top.)

On admin/structure/block, select the block you just created, and assign it a region where it should appear. Its name is *View: Front page*, if you didn't change the default one, which is *None*.

[image: screenshot]

This is the result.

[image: screenshot]

I changed the access settings because I enabled the view which was not enabled, yet. If you are already using the *Front page* view is not necessary to change the access settings, if not in the case you want the access settings for the block to be different from the page settings. In this case, be sure to select "This block (override) as in the fourth screenshot.

Comment: This is a quite broad topic. You can find some information on [Theming Views in Drupal with Templates and Preprocess Functions](http://goo.gl/13V08), or [Drupal 7 Views: templates and preprocess](http://goo.gl/ItetI). It's impossible to answer your question in a comment. If you have a specific question, you can ask a new question, provided the question is not as generic as "How do I theme a block created with the Views module?"

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps that you need to follow to achieve your task:

1. Add a new content view with fields (block display)
2. Add the filter criterion "Content: Promoted to front page = YES"
3. Add the filter criterion "Content: Type Is one of article/news/video"
4. Change "Display a specified number of items" to 10
5. Navigate to "admin/structure/block"
6. Find the view, and place it where you want it to be displayed

Comment: i know, my mean how to print using views module.

Comment: @BaTmaN check the **edited** answer